# Correct use of article 'the'

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

> **The indians** are genetically incapable of being good or outstanding sportsman.

Here i think it should be only **indians**. If i want to use *the* then use as *the indian*  not *the indians*.

Am i right? If 'no' then give the correct explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In a sentence like the example "The Indians" means "Indians as a group, and is perfectly grammatical. "The Indian" means a single, specific Indian. Saying "Indians are incapable" has much the same meaning as "The Indians are incapable" but does not emphasize the group as much.

Many people now consider such statements which assign properties, particularly negative properties, to entire groups, to be impolite or even racist. But such statements have been common in English through much of its history, and some still make them.

Comment: What about the lower case of 'indian' and the singular 'sportsman'?

Comment: It should be capitalised Indians, and pluralised sportsmen. Either "The Indians are genetically incapable of being good or outstanding sportsmen." or "Indians are genetically incapable of being good or outstanding sportsmen." It's also a bit tautological - if they already can't be good, there's no need to say they can't be outstanding; that would be a given. And it's also clearly wrong - India has some brilliant sportsmen. Look at their cricketers!

Comment: @Showsni I'm sorry to have missed the missing capitol and the lack of number agreement. You are right there. As to "good" vs "outstanding" I do not think the latter included the former. In this usage, to be a "good sportsman" means to be particularly ethical, while to be an "outstanding sportsman" means to be a high-quality athlete.